# UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile skips @2x on iPhone6Plus

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to know if I missed something or if I encountered a new retina bug once again. My app on the iPhone6Plus looks like a scaled version app from the non-retina era and here's why.

For most of my needs, I use `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFiles:]` because I only load them once and I don't need the system to cache images like `[UIImage imageNamed:]` does. The former has to be given a full or partial path (in most cases a path using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]` suffices), the other one the name of a resource in the application's main bundle.

It is my belief that `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFiles:]` and `[UIImage imageNamed:]` should behave the same when resolving the right image file to use according to the device's scaling. Well it doesn't seem to be case.

For instance, if no @3x images are available but 1.0 and @2x images are, the iPhone6Plus will simply ignore the @2x images when using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFiles:]` unless an absolute path to the @2x image file is given.

On the other hand, `[UIImage imageNamed:]` does load the @2x image on the iPhone6Plus if the @3x image is not available. The @2x image is there, but on a device with a scaling greater than 2.0, `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFiles:]` just resolves to the 1.0 image instantly.

Comment: the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html) clearly says the `+imageNamed:` method tries to resolve the filename for the current screen; opposite to the `+ imageWithContentsOfFiles:` which loads the certain file directly (as you mentioned in your question as your experience). that looks pretty straightforward from the docs...

Comment: Then maybe they should not make it work at all on other devices. On retina4 devices (5, 5s), `imageWithContentsOfFile:` loads the appropriate @2x image, and the iPhone6Plus will load the @3x image if available. My point is that the resolving behaviour of `imageNamed:` is half implemented in `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, hence my question: bug or I missed something? Which also begs the question: what if I want to load the very specific 1.0 image? Make my app bigger by packaging a copy of the 1.0 version in a different resource file?

Comment: I also noticed `ImageView`s in the Interface Builder won't load @2x versions, it will fallback to images of scale 1.0 instantly if the app runs on an iPhone 6 Plus.